# Change SharePoint 2013 Page Title

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, page-layout, title

I am looking to fix the "page name vs title (in the Title field)" issue in SharePoint 2013.  Currently, whatever name is given to the page (EX: default)  shows on the page in the title area.

I would like to actually show what is put in the "Title" field to show as the title on a page (

**EX:** page name = default and title field is Coffee Bean Company) = page title should show "Coffee Bean Company".

**P.S.** I am working in SharePoint 2013, cannot alter the Seattle master page (not an option in our company) and the site is a Publishing site.

Any thoughts would be so greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**You have two Titles in your Page**

- Site Title (Colored by red).
- Page Title (Colored by green).

[image]

---

**To Edit the Site Title (Colored by red):**

- Go to Site Setting.
- Below `Look and Feel` > `Title, Description, and Logo`  > Edit Title as you prefer.

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can use SharePoint Designer as the following

- Open SharePoint Designer > From the left navigation > click on Home Page Name > Edit the title field as shown below

[image]

Both ways lead to the same result :)

---

**To Edit Page Title (Colored by green):**

- From Site Setting> Select Edit Page.
- At `Title` Field > change your page Title as you prefer.

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can also edit the page properties from the `Pages` library in the `Site Content` as the following:

- Open Site Content > Pages > Find the default Page > Click on Edit Button.
- Edit the Title Field as you prefer

[image]

Comment: Hi there,  Thank you everyone for the posts....
However, on a publishing page, whatever gets put into the "Title" field does not show up on the page.   Lists, wiki pages, doc libraries  will show the title field however not for a publishing page....

I believe I saw the masterpage has this option commented out....  
This same issue exists when linking into a page that shows data into a folder....lots of %20 for spaces etc....   I will try to grab some screen shots in the next post...   thanks much  csm

Comment: Not sure how to post an image...sorry

Comment: the above steps for publishing page! you can edit your question and add the image !

Comment: super...I am adding a shot of what I am getting and what I need to show on publishing pages....  I have tried adding title code in a layout page but not getting the results I was looking for or the page would error...  hope this helps.   any thoughts?  thanks so much csm